# Consolidate multiple work in one and want to copy only 2 row from each worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a macro that consolidating all workbook in one excel and copy their entire data from each worksheet.

but I only want to copy 2 rows from each consolidated sheet which is rows A2 and A3.

As I am not very good in VBA but I have created this macro from various source.
Please help on this.

```
Sub CombilnedWorkBook_and_Sheets()
Dim J As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim varFieldName            As Variant
Dim lngLoop                 As Long
Dim rngFound                As Range
Dim rngCopy                 As Range
Dim lngLastRow              As Long
Dim lngLastRow1             As Long
Dim lngCol                  As Long
Dim wksTarget               As Worksheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set wksTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidated")

varFieldName = Array("Patient Name", "DOB", "Admit_date", "Discharge_date", "Primary_DX_Code", "BPS PDF", "Consultation Doc", "Discharge Agreement", "EMF PDF", "Financial PDF", "ID & Insurance Card", "Lab Report PDF", "Legal History", "Medical Docs PDF", "Progress Notes PDF", "Pass Documentation", "Treatment Agreement", "Utilization Review", "User")

Path = Sheet1.Range("C9").Value
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")

  Do While Filename <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
       For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
         Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
       Next Sheet
     Workbooks(Filename).Close savechanges:=False
     Filename = Dir()
  Loop

    wksTarget.Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1).ClearContents


        For J = 2 To Sheets.Count
            lngLastRow1 = wksTarget.Cells(wksTarget.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Sheets(J).Activate
            For lngLoop = 0 To UBound(varFieldName)
            Set rngFound = Range("A1").EntireRow.Find(varFieldName(lngLoop))
            If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
                lngCol = rngFound.Column
                lngLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, lngCol).End(xlUp).Row

                With ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(lngCol)
                    Set rngCopy = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
                End With
             rngCopy.Copy Destination:=wksTarget.Cells(lngLastRow1, lngLoop + 1)

                    Set rngFound = Nothing
                    Set rngCopy = Nothing
                    lngCol = 0
                    lngLastRow = 0
           End If
           Next lngLoop
        Next

    Sheets(1).Select

    Columns("A:Z").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            For Each ws In Worksheets
             If ws.Name <> "Consolidated" And ws.Name <> "Run Macro" Then ws.Delete
            Next

            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    MsgBox "File has been coppied Successfully"

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean rows 2 and 3 or cells A2 and A3?

Comment: If you mean rows, then you need to edit the line with `Set rngCopy =` to have `.range("2:3")` on the right hand side. Otherwise, use "A2:A3" instead of "2:3".

Answer (score 0):

Does the below do what you want? Sorry for bad formatting and indentation, written on mobile.

```
Option explicit
Sub CombilnedWorkBook_and_Sheets()
'Dim J As long'


Dim lngLoop                 As Long
Dim rngFound                As Range
'Dim rngCopy                 As Range'
Dim lngLastRow              As Long
Dim lngLastRow1             As Long
Dim lngCol                  As Long
Dim wksTarget               As Worksheet

Application.screenupdating = false

Set wksTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidated")

Dim varFieldName            As Variant

varFieldName = Array("Patient Name", "DOB", "Admit_date", "Discharge_date", "Primary_DX_Code", "BPS PDF", "Consultation Doc", "Discharge Agreement", "EMF PDF", "Financial PDF", "ID & Insurance Card", "Lab Report PDF", "Legal History", "Medical Docs PDF", "Progress Notes PDF", "Pass Documentation", "Treatment Agreement", "Utilization Review", "User")

Path = Sheet1.Range("C9").Value
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")

Dim ws As Worksheet

' Code below loops through worksheets only, will ignore sheets/charts'

  Do While len(Filename) > 0
Dim wb as Workbook

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True)
With wb
       For Each ws In .worksheets
         ws.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
       Next ws
     .Close savechanges:=False
End with
Set wb = nothing
     Filename = Dir()


    Loop
     wksTarget.Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1).ClearContents

    For each ws in wkstarget.parent.worksheets
                lngLastRow1 = wksTarget.Cells(wksTarget.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

                For lngLoop = lbound(varfieldname) To UBound(varFieldName)

    With ws
                Set rngFound = .Range("A1").EntireRow.Find(varFieldName(lngLoop),,xlvalues,xlwhole,xlbyrows,xlnext)

                If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
                    lngCol = rngFound.Column
                    lngLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, lngCol).End(xlUp).Row

                        .Range(.cells(2,lngcol),.cells(3,lngcol)).Copy Destination:=wksTarget.Cells(lngLastRow1, lngLoop + 1)

                        Set rngFound = Nothing
                        'Set rngCopy = Nothing'
                        lngCol = 0
                        lngLastRow = 0
               End If
    End with
               Next lngLoop
            Next ws

        Wkstarget.parent.workSheets(1).Columns("A:Z").EntireColumn.AutoFit

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                For Each ws In wkstarget.parent.Worksheets
                 If ws.Name <> "Consolidated" And ws.Name <> "Run Macro" Then ws.Delete
                Next ws
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True

                Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        MsgBox "File has been coppied Successfully"

    End Sub
```

However, I don't understand why you copied all the worksheets over, just to delete them in the end. Seems more efficient to have just copied the values between workbooks. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I have written code that deletes all copy sheet in the end. but I am not able to run your code it populating syntax error on WITH operator.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the code. Try now? I don't have access to a PC right now, so I can't test it.